# Можно ли как-то попросить параметризованный тип быть наследником конкретного класса?

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++

Я делаю свою реализацию списка (попрошу без "велосипедов", вот хочется мне сделать так). Я хочу чтобы параметризованный тип обязательно являлся наследником.

```
class Item {
    Item& prev;
    Item& next;
};

class SomeClass : Item {...};
class SomeClass2 {...};

template <class T (SHOULD EXTEND ITEM)> List {...};

int main(){
    List<SomeClass> list; // Okay
    List<SomeClass2> list2; // Error [SomeClass2 does not extend Item]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `static_assert`. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Item
{
    Item &next;
    Item &prev;
};

template <typename T>
struct List 
{
    static_assert(  std::is_base_of<Item, T>::value, 
                    "Template argument must derive class Item" );
};

struct A : Item {};
struct B {};

int main() 
{
    List<A> l1;
//  List<B> l2; // ошибка компиляции

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.